# Criterio of Convergence in the set of all(bounded or unbounded) sequences of complex numbers

Tags: complex-analysis, functional-analysis

Show that in the space S we have $x_n \rightarrow x$ if and
    only if $e_{j}^{\left( n\right) }\rightarrow e_j$ for all $j=1,2, \dots, $ where $x_n =\left(e_{j}^{\left( n\right) } \right) $ and $x=\left(e_j \right) $

Note: S is the set of all(bounded or unbounded) sequences of complex numbers 
and the metric $d$ is defined by $$d\left(y,z \right)= \sum_{j=1}^{\infty}{\frac{1}{2^j}\frac{|y_j-z_j|}{1+|y_j-z_j|}} $$

My aproach:

Suppose $x_n \rightarrow x$ in S. For every $j>0$, given any $\epsilon>0$ there is $N$ such that for all $n>N$ we have:

$$ \frac{1}{2^j} \frac{|e_j-e_{j}^{\left( n\right)}|}{1+|e_j-e_{j}^{\left( n\right)}|} \leq \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}{\frac{1}{2^k} \frac{|e_k-e_{k}^{\left( n\right)}|}{1+|e_k-e_{k}^{\left( n\right)}|}}=d\left(x,x_n \right)< \frac{1}{2^j} \frac{\epsilon}{1+\epsilon}$$

Then 
    \begin{eqnarray*}
  \frac{|e_j-e_{j}^{\left( n\right)|}}{1+|e_j-e_{j}^{\left( n\right)|}} &\leq& \frac{\epsilon}{1+\epsilon}\\
  |e_j-e_{j}^{\left( n\right)|\left( 1+\epsilon\right)} &\leq& \epsilon \left( 1+|e_j-e_{j}^{\left( n\right)}|\right) \\
  |e_j-e_{j}^{\left( n\right)}|&\leq& \epsilon  
 \end{eqnarray*}
This show that $e_{j}^{\left( n\right) }\rightarrow e_j$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$.

Conversely, suppose $e_{j}^{\left( n\right) }\rightarrow e_j$ for all $j$.
Given any $\epsilon > 0$ there is $N_j$ such that for all $n>N_j$ we have:
$$\frac{1}{2^j} \frac{|e_j-e_{j}^{\left( n\right)}|}{1+|e_j-e_{j}^{\left( n\right)}|}< |e_j-e_{j}^{\left( n\right)}|<\frac{1}{2^j}\epsilon$$

**If there is $N$ such that for all j $N>N_j$ then for $n>N$ we have:
$$\frac{1}{2^j} \frac{|e_j-e_{j}^{\left( n\right)}|}{1+|e_j-e_{j}^{\left( n\right)}|}< \frac{1}{2^j}\epsilon$$ for every $j$ and $$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}{\frac{1}{2^j} \frac{|e_j-e_{j}^{\left( n\right)}|}{1+|e_j-e_{j}^{\left( n\right)}|}} <\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}{\frac{1}{2^k}\epsilon}=\epsilon$$**

But I do not know choose $N$; Could someone help me with it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First choose $N$ such that $\sum\limits_{k=N+1}^{\infty} \frac  1{2^{n}} <\epsilon$. Then $d(x,y) <\sum\limits_{k=1}^{N} \frac 1{2^{k}} \frac {|e_k -e_k^{(n)}|} {1+|e_k -e_k^{(n)}|}+\epsilon$. Can  you use this to finish the proof?

Comment: Then I choose the max among $N_1,\dots,N_N, N$

Comment: @CarlosAndresHenaoAcevedo That is right.